A simple visual indicator (LED light?) when a USB fan is on
I have a USB fan, some distance away from me, which I use occasionally. It's plugged into a charger and it has a manual switch. I sometimes forget to turn it off, because it's very quiet so I can't hear whether it's on or off. I'd like to have a visual indicator, like a LED light, that would tell me when the fan is on. The fan doesn't have its own LED. Is there some cheap, non-time-consuming way to add such a LED light? It could be either inline, between the USB cable and the fan, or mounted on the fan and detecting its state via some sensor. The closest thing I can think of is a USB tester (link below), that displays the current being drawn. But such testers are always on, plus I'd have to move closer to read the amp value. I'd prefer a visual indicator that's "on" ONLY when the fan is on and which doesn't require reading a value.
USB tester

if you don't want to wire it, use a usb splitter, a usb switch, and a usb light/lamp.

Thanks. Good idea but it won't work. The fan is always off by default, unless you press the "on" button, which also handles other functions (press longer: off etc). The button doesn't simply close a circuit, it triggers some IC logic or some such.

You can add a resistor and LED in parallel with the fan.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thanks. For this to work, I'd have to open the fan's enclosure, because this has to hook up into the circuit PAST the manual switch, right? I was hoping there would be a quick add-on solution (not opening the enclosure), but I'll give it a try :)

@MrSparkly Yes, past the switch.  It's the only way to keep it simple as you requested.  I updated the schematic to show the switch.
